# Keeping trailing 0 when converting from str to float

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I have the following problem when converting a number with trailing zeros from string to float:

```
a = 1.100
string_a = str(a)
float_a = float(string_a)
float_a = 1.1
```

Is there a way to convert str to float while keeping the trailing 0s at the end?

Comment: Why would you need to? They are exactly the same value.

Comment: No once you create `a` it is a float, not a decimal, you can't expect it to have any trailing 0s

Comment: I'm actually planning on converting float_a back to str later. It's part of a file name and I need to keep all the digits in it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The zeroes aren't kept in the first place:

```
>>> 1.100
1.1
>>> 1.100 == 1.1
True
```

But you can use string formatting to preserve them when you print it out:

```
>>> 'It works: {:0.3f}'.format(1.1)
'It works: 1.100'
>>> 'And even with integers: {:0.3f}'.format(10000)
'And even with integers: 10000.000'
```