# float number with leading zero at end on python

Tags: python

I want to convert string number to float and keep zeros at the end like this f=float('.270') and f should be 0.270, not 0.27 or '0.270' how I can do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keeping trailing 0 when converting from str to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127804/keeping-trailing-0-when-converting-from-str-to-float) (Also, I think you meant _trailing_ zero)

Comment: Keep clear on the the difference between data and it's representation. a float will never be `"0.270"`, but the representation of the float `0.27` can be shown like that. When you want to "show" a value a certain way, say, 3 decimal places, then think in terms of representation

Comment: i tested it when i used result='{:0.3f}'.format('0.270') result is '0.270' and string  not 0.270 and float

Comment: `format()` is a string formatting method, and will not convert `result` to a float value. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16127812/5070837) answer from the earlier link used  `format()` to preserve the trailing zero _while printing to console_. You are _not_ losing precision when the float value is `0.27`, as stated in that answer, since zeroes aren't kept in the first place.

Comment: for `float` there is no difference between values 0.270 and 0.27 and all calculations are the same. Your problem exists only when you want to display it but then you convert it to string with `'{:0.3f}'.format(float_value)` and print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending of the application, you should use the Decimal lib - specially if you are dealing with critical calculations like money

https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/decimal.html

```
import decimal
decimal.getcontext().prec = 3
f = decimal.Decimal('0.270')
print(f)
```

Or simply `"%.3f" % f`

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered saving the float as a string rather than a float? If needed for calculations then it can be casted to a float. If you need to have this for significant figures, then [this article on rounding numbers in Python](https://stackabuse.com/rounding-numbers-in-python/) should help. It uses the `format()` method.

I hope this was able to help!

phylo